# Serializing Xpo objects through WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, serialization, xpo

Good evening/morning everyone,

before posting this issue, i've been sending my objects with a traditional way from the client side ( aspx page ) to a WCF data service, the approch i've been using was to convert all attributes to a string and send them after joining them, and in the server side i split the string chain and i construct my object and store it. now by working i found that this method is no longer udapted to what i'm planing to do and it will take me much time. so i've decided to find a way of serializing my xpo objects and send them to the service. been browsing google before coming up to SOF but i didnt find a good tutorial for someone not much familiar with serialization mechanism.

please give me some track to a solution which will reduce lot of time.

i think its a good point to descibe the architecture of my project:

i have a asp web application which contains some pages, and in the server side i have a wcf data service(5.0) which contains all my methods, i'm using XPO as a ORM and all my objects inherit from xpobject.

Thank you in advance and by the way i want to thank the mods/admins/members of SOF for their work helping dummies/intermediate and even experts.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective, it is not recommended to serialize/deserialize the object graph with XPO. Instead you should either [serialize the datastore](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/xpo/archive/2006/04/13/xpo-is-good-for-distributed-applications.aspx) or [serialize the object layer](http://www.expandframework.com/blog/7-michael-proctor/93-how-to-serialize-your-xpo.html).

That said, if you need to serialize objects for import/export, have a look at the [eXpand module](http://apobekiaris.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/collaborating-with-xaf-and-io-module.html).

As with all things DevExpress, the best place to ask questions is [the support centre](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but none of links above guide me in a real helpful track. now it's been three days and i'm stucked. hope some one in SOF provides me with some ideas or tracks to follow. because this idea of serializaing my objects manually ( join and split the string chains ) isnt good anymore for me because my objects are getting complicated with collection of objects. thank you SOF community in advance.